# Laravel - 'Route' chamada sem um comando para isto?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

Estou fazendo um teste usando Laravel, jQuery e PHP.

Tenho rotas, ação em jQuery, métodos em controllers e duas views-blade, uma para fornecer elementos de busca (FaturamentoListaView.blade.php) e outra para exibir o resultado (FaturamentoAprovarView.blade.php).

O projeto é simples: 
Tenho uma lista de registros provenientes de um banco de dados, que são carregados numa tabela de uma 'view-blade'.
Junto a cada linha dessa tabela, é criado um botão 'a quente' para cada registro recebido.
Quando se clica em quaisquer desses botões, uma ação 'click' do jQuery, associada ao botão pressionado, dispara um método PHP que retorna um registro de outra tabela.
Este registro é passado a uma instrução Laravel/PHP que abre uma outra 'view-blade', a fim de que se mostre os valores do registro encontrado.

A 'route' inicial, que abre a view com os registros é:

```
Route::get("/pesquisar-Faturamento-verificarCobranca",
 "FaturamentoController@verificarCobranca");
```

O framento do código  da 'view', chamada pela 'route' acima, que no evento da abertura carrega registros do banco de dados, é:

```
@foreach($pendencias as $p)
  <tr>
   <td>
      <button class="claBtnFaturamentoAbrir" title="{{$p->identificador}}">Abrir este</button>
   </td>
   <td>
      {{$p->siglaaprovador}}
   </td>
   <td>
      {{$p->siglaredator}}
   </td>
   <td>
      {{$p->vencimento}}
   </td>
   <td>
      {{$p->cobrado}}
   </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

O clique no botão

```
<button class="claBtnFaturamentoAbrir" title="{{$p->identificador}}">Abrir este</button>
```

provoca um evento no jQuery, que é

```
jQuery(".claBtnFaturamentoAbrir").on("click",function(){
  var identificador=jQuery(this).prop("title");
      jQuery.get("pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario",{identificador:identificador},function(){
    });//get
});//idBtnFaturamentoAbrir on click
```

O jQuery, através do método .get e do parâmetro {identificador:identificador}, provoca uma outra 'route' que, por sua vez, vai provocar um método no respectivo 'controller':

```
Route::get("/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario", "FaturamentoController@verFormulario");
```

O método, no 'controller', tem o seguinte fragmento de código:

```
public function verFormulario(){

$identificador=$_GET['identificador'];

$resultado=DB::select('instrução SQL omitida para maior clareza');

return view('FaturamentoAprovarView')->with("fatura",$resultado);
}
```

A última instrução, então, como mostrada acima é

```
return view('FaturamentoAprovarView')->with("fatura",$resultado);
```

Mas não é isto que acontece.
A 'view' 'FaturamentoAprovarView' não é chamada; ela não abre. A tela permanece na primeira tela, aquela que a 'route' inicial chamou.
A permanência, entretanto, é ilusória, porque na verdade a 'view' inicial é recarregada, ao invés de ser sobrescrita pela chamada no 'controller'.

Pesquisando a área do programador, no log do Chrome, confirma-se que o método é chamado, mas a outra 'route', a inicial, é que prevalece, por ser a última:

```
jquery.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET "http://172.16.0.30/laravel/tempo/public/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario?
identificador=29638_1472048778961_121

Navigated to http://172.16.0.30/laravel/tempo/public/pesquisar-Faturamento-verificarCobranca?
redator_tabusuarios=fulano de tal
```

O que eu desejo é que o código pare na primeira linha do log acima.

Answer (score 1):

Se foi o que eu entendi, você precisa mudar de rota e a sua ação é via JQuery, não é?! faça o seguinte:

Primeiro, faça um teste da rota '/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario' em seu navegador, passando um valor qualquer no identificador para certificar se ela está funcionando.

Depois, vá no JS e ao invés de usar o JQuery.get() no evento do click, faça um simples redirect usando o `window.location.href` passando a rota pra onde você quer ir, por exemplo:

```
window.location.href = '/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario?
identificador=29638_1472048778961_121';
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Lucas, parcialmente me resolve, mas tive problema em outro ponto. Resolvi modificar a rota para 
Route::get("/pesquisar-Faturamento-verFormulario/{identificador}", ['as' => "abrirAprovacao", 'uses' => "FaturamentoController@verFormulario"]); e a blade para 
<a href="{{ route('abrirAprovacao', $p->identificador ) }}">Clique aqui</a>